# Windows 7 icon alignment

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, icons, alignment

I have downloaded several youtube videos to my video folder, but they are not in the order I want them, if I try to reposition them, they fly back to their original positions. What can I do to make them moveable?

Comment: Windows explorer I presume, as this obviously is not a "Google" or Chrome issue. How do you want the files sorted?

Comment: That function was removed in Windows 7 and 8 (except desktop).

Answer (score 0):

This feature was removed in Windows 7 because ([according to Ryan T](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-to-manually-arrange-folders-in-windows-7/91d630f0-c18d-4eaa-889b-e0ecaffa5a94) - a Microsoft Support Engineer) in Windows XP, icons would overlap each other, but there is a way to get this feature back, but it involves editing the registry, and that could be harmful, so make sure you back up first or create a restore point! I just tested it so I can confirm it works:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/92758-windows-explorer-auto-arrange-disable.html

The above link provides a batch file to do this

or this:

http://www.unawave.de/windows-7-tipps/disable-sorting-auto-arrange.html?lang=EN

---

In case this link dies, I will copy and paste the important details here (without images):

> To activate the free sorting for each of the 5 file types ("General Items", "Pictures", "Documents", "Music" and "Videos") in the registry must be set up a new template for each of the 5 file types that allows the free sorting. Therefore open registry editor ("regedit") and go to this section:
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\
>
> There create this new key: `(5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7)`

Add these two entries as values for this key:

```
"FFLAGS"=dword:43000001 (hex)
"Mode"=dword:00000004 (hex)
```

> With this key `{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}` a template for new folders of type "General Items" was created. For the other four folder types create a template in the same way:

```
Documents:  {7D49D726-3C21-4F05-99AA-FDC2C9474656}
Music:  {94D6DDCC-4A68-4175-A374-BD584A510B78}
Pictures:   {B3690E58-E961-423B-B687-386EBFD83239}
Videos: {5FA96407-7E77-483C-AC93-691D05850DE8}
```

> For already existing folder Windows 7 has saved the folder settings (without free sorting) in the registry branch HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags. Here can be seen a long list of numbers, each corresponding to a saved folder setting. They should have deleted all individually - but this is quite monotonous. More easily is the following method: First export the entries under "AllFolders" into a separate file. Then delete the complete menu branch "Bags"
>
> This erases all saved folder settings at one stroke - but also the menu branch "AllFolders". To import the menu branch "AllFolders" again it needs only a double click to the previously exported file "AllFolders.reg".
>
> [This](http://www.unawave.de/medien/Windows-7/Sortieren/Free-sorting-for-Windows7.zip) Batch file does all the above steps automatically in one step:
>
> Step 1: Add the 5 Keys for "General folder", "Documents folder", "Music folder", "Pictures >folder" and "Videos folder"
>
> Step 2: Export everything under the key "AllFolders" into a separate file "AllFolders.reg"
>
> Step 3: Delete everything under the key "Bags"
>
> Step 4: Import again exported file "AllFolders.reg"
>
> Step 5: Delete exported file "AllFolders.reg"