# Turn off sort on a group of files in a folder

Tags: windows-explorer

How can I turn off the sort function on a group of files (pictures) within a folder?  My goal is to arrange a large number of pictures from a number of people (different file names) into a list that I can use for a slide show.  I want to be able to move files around in the list without it auto sorting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 icon alignment](http://superuser.com/questions/759228/)

Answer (score 0):

I have a file which works on windows 8, don't know about others.
[Download](http://www.eightforums.com/attachments/tutorials/8296d1346735841-windows-explorer-auto-arrange-disable-windows-8-enable_windows_8_explorer_auto_arrange.bat)

1. Download and save it on your PC.
2. Run.